# fatal error: 'limits.h' file not found MacOs Catalina

Tags: macos, openssl, macos-catalina, macos-mojave

So I have script which builds openssl for my android project all works fine when I run this script locally on my Mojave machine, however seems to fail on Jenkins server running on Catalina with following error.

```
In file included from apps/app_rand.c:10:
In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
./e_os.h:13:11: fatal error: 'limits.h' file not found
# include <limits.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [apps/app_rand.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have already tried updating my CommandLineTools using xcode-select --install, no luck.
I have tried 'open /< some-location >/macosheaders.pkg' but unfortunately it does not exist on my machine.

Comment: limits.h is a C header file providing values for min and max limits of built in types.
Seems they are missing from your machine, possibly related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372032/usr-include-missing-on-macos-catalina-with-xcode-11

Comment: does not seem not work for me